# Syncfusion Blazor Redirect when Kanban clicked

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, syncfusion-blazor

I am currently trying to redirect the user in syncfusion to another page when clicked, but everytime I get the same exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Kanban.SfKanban`1.ColumnChange()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Kanban.SfKanban`1.<RefreshLayout>d__143.MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Kanban.SfKanban`1.<ClientPropertyChangeHandler>d__131.MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Kanban.SfKanban`1.<OnParametersSetAsync>d__346.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion>d__22.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<GetErrorHandledTask>d__71.MoveNext()
```

My Code from the events to trigger the redirect:

```
<KanbanEvents TValue="TasksModel" DialogOpen="@OnDialogOpen" CardDoubleClick="@OnCardClicked"></KanbanEvents>

private void OnDialogOpen(DialogOpenEventArgs<TasksModel> args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
}

private void OnCardClicked(CardClickEventArgs<TasksModel> args)
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo("test/" + args.Data.Id);
}
```